# MySQL Conventions?

Tags: php, mysql

I just moved my website to a new server (Shared to VPS)

I expected errors, and the only error that is really puzzling me is this SQL statement.

```
echo mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_online_now")
```

This returns nothing! And if I try the `mysql_num_rows`, it returns

```
mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource..
```

If I query another table though eg:

```
echo mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users")
```

It works fine.

I am guessing it's something to do with the naming of the table? It worked fine on my previous host, is there some setting I should modify?

Update:
Figured out. The server is still going thru DNS changes, and the mySQL is completely messed up. DNS has finally updated!

Comment: Well, does a table of that name exist?

Comment: However, table names should be enclosed in backticks: `\`` not quotes. But that can't be the reason if your second query works.

Comment: Yes, I remove the quotes, and yes; the tables exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to find  out what error you get by adding `or die` like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users_online_now`") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also make sure that you have already connected to mysql database successfully, see these functions for that:

**[`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)**
   **[`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)**

**Note:** In names you should use **backtick character (`)** rather than single quote.

**Update:**

If you have a MySQL Database that has a table with a damaged Index, you may get an error:

```
 Incorrect file format [table name]
```

**[Here is the possible solution.](http://w3helper.com/repair-mysql-table-damaged-index-incorrect-file-format/#more-107)**

.

**More threads on the problem:**

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,18436,18436

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mysql-crash-on-startup-incorrect-file-format-host-464422/

http://www.devcomments.com/SQL-Error-incorrect-file-format-to138833.htm

Comment: I'm connected normally, and that mysql_error() returned:
Incorrect file format 'users_online_now'

Comment: @Moe: It seems that the database is not repairable. Do you have the backup of it somewhere?

Comment: I do have a backup. I'll try re-creating it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the [MySQL result resource](http://php.net/mysql.resources) to [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) like so:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users_online_now`");
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

You should also [use **`` ` ``** for table names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) if they need to be quoted. But in this case the table name does not need to be quoted.